# Webpack compiled bundle js not used in react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In my app js

```
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, '/dist')))
```

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/main.js",
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, "/dist/js/"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  mode: "development"
  // ...
};
```

In my footer.hbs

```
<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

In my package.json Scripts

```
"startw": "webpack-dev-server --open",
"server": "node app.js",
```

When I make a change in any js file, webpack is compiling but it does not overwrite /js/bundle.js. How can I make webpack recompile my changed bundle js to overwrite dist/js/bundle.js ?
I have tried 
https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server
and
webpack-dev-middleware

For production, I use

```
"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p --watch",
```

This compiled as expected to dist/js/bundle.js but this is tedious to run it each time I make a simple change to a js file.

I want to inject the auto compiled output js to use it in my app. I dont mind refreshing the page myself and do not care if I dont get to use HMR.

Comment: webpack dev server compiles files to memory, they dont compile to disk. You should use "normal" webpack.

Comment: thanks. I use normal webpack and it writes to file but that does not compile as and when I make changes to js file. I use webpack dev middleware to recompile - How can I use the recompiled bundle js in my app ?

Comment: If you're not very familiar with Webpack setup, I'd recommend using `create-react-app` until you _really_ need to change config. That said -- you'll need to point the script tag in `footer.hbs` to whatever port webpack-dev-server is running on in dev, and change that in production. I haven't used handlebars in a while so I'm not sure how to pass env variables in, but in plain js that would look something like `<script src="${isProd ? '' : 'http://localhost:3000'}/bundle.js"></script>`, assuming WDS is on port 3000.

Comment: Thanks Zac. I did try both create-react-app and React-Starter-Kit. I had to eject Create-React-App but with hbs and my entry being in the root folder cra was not working. I managed to make hot reload work with cra but my site was not loading hbs and styles and had weird axios 404 errors.

Comment: Hi Zac - I think your comment fixed my issue - <script src="/bundle.js"></script> - I added this and I see that webpack is serving the js from memory... Thanks.. I will just change it when I goto prod.